# Python code inside javascript is not recognized for visual studio code

Tags: javascript, python-3.7

I have some JS code inside an HTML file as `<script></script>`, but the back end calculations are made by python, in **pycharm**, this py code is recognized and working well, but in vs code is detected as an issue:

> '(' expected. *js*

My question is, why is VS code detecting this as an error and how can I fix it?

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("switch").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("stay").style.visibility = "hidden";

        {% if error %}             #this code is python, not JS
            alert('{ error }')
        {% endif %}

    var clicked = false;
    var randomize = Math.random(1,4);

    function shuffle(array) {
        var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
```

[image: VS code screen]

Comment: I don't think you can use python in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using Jinja2 (or Django) templates. You need to have a plugin installed in Visual Studio Code to handle these templates.

There are a couple of choices but this is actively maintained:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=samuelcolvin.jinjahtml